# How to Pin Text to a GameObject

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Is it possible to pin a Text object in unity to specific GameObject? What I am trying to do is, to create a runtime gameobject and pin text onto that gameobject. I don't know how to create this as I am a beginner in Unity game development.

```js
// Code for Game Objects.. 
#pragma strict

// Variable for Get Components
var getComponents : GameObject; 

// For Moving the Box
var speed : float = 10f;
var movementVector = Vector3.zero;

function Start() {
    // Run Time Cube Generator
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++ )
    {
        if(flag) {
            cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            cube.name = "RedCube" + Tagcounter;

            cube.AddComponent(GUIText);

            // Render Cubes 
            cube.transform.position = Vector2(posx,posy); 
            cube.transform.localScale = Vector2(1,1);       
            cube.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
            //  cube.AddComponent(Rigidbody);
            //  cube.AddComponent(GUIText);
            cube.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f); 
            posy+=2;

            cube.gameObject.guiText.text = counter.ToString();  

            cube.gameObject.guiText.material.color = Color.white;

            //  cube.guiText.text = Vector3.forward(posx,posy,0);

            counter++;

            // Text Working
            Debug.Log(cube.gameObject.guiText.text);
        }

        Tagcounter++;
    }
}

function Update()
{
    var Redcube = GameObject.Find("RedCube0");
    var Redcube1 = GameObject.Find("RedCube1");
    var Redcube2 = GameObject.Find("RedCube2");
    var Redcube3 = GameObject.Find("RedCube3");
    var Redcube4 = GameObject.Find("RedCube4");
    var Redcube5 = GameObject.Find("RedCube5");

    // For Upward Movement 
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        // For Moving Upward
        Redcube.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube1.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube2.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube3.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube4.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube5.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);                  
    }

    // For Downward Movement
    if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {      
        // For Moving Downwards
        Redcube.transform.Translate(0f,-1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);     
        Redcube1.transform.Translate(0f,-1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);     
        Redcube2.transform.Translate(0f,-1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);     
        Redcube3.transform.Translate(0f,-1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);     
        Redcube4.transform.Translate(0f,-1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);     
        Redcube5.transform.Translate(0f,-1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);           
    }

    // For Left Movement
    if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {      
        // IF one moves Left 
        cube.transform.Translate(-1f * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);     

        // Others Move Up First 
        Redcube.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube1.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube2.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube3.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube4.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);   
        Redcube5.transform.Translate(0f,1f * Time.deltaTime,0f);                  
    }

    // For Right Movement
    if( Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {      
        cube.transform.Translate(1f * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);  
        // Others Move Up First 
        Redcube.transform.Translate(1f * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);   
        Redcube1.transform.Translate(1f * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);   
        Redcube2.transform.Translate(1f * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);   
        Redcube3.transform.Translate(1f * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);   
        Redcube4.transform.Translate(1f * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);   
        Redcube5.transform.Translate(1f * Time.deltaTime,0f,0f);                          
    }   
}

function OnGUI() { 
    // Whole Screen     
    GUI.Box (Rect (0,0,100,50), "Top-left");
    GUI.Box (Rect (Screen.width - 100,0,100,50), "Top-right");
    GUI.Box (Rect (0,Screen.height - 50,100,50), "Bottom-left");
    GUI.Box (Rect (Screen.width - 100,Screen.height - 50,100,50), "Bottom-right");
    // Label 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want text object to be directly attached to your gameobject, you can use

```
var text = gameObjectName.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
text.text = "Some text";
```

I`m not sure if MeshRenderer marked as required component for textMesh. If it is not, you also would have to add MeshRenderer manually.
A bit more complex, but a much better practice would be to create child object containing text only and exposing it in parent object. Like that:

```
var cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
var textHolder = new GameObject("Text");
textHolder.transform.parent = cube.transform;
var text = textHolderAddComponent<TextMesh>();
```

Hope it helps.